# Is sanitize_title_with_dashes formatting function too liberal (in terms of accepted characters)?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, formatting, encoding

`sanitize_title_with_dashes` (see code below for reference) is the function Wordpress uses to format "pretty" urls. However, contrary to the function's comment header, it allows much more than alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-). It also allows signs like °, etc.

How would I go about really allowing only alphanumeric characters and dashes?

```
/**
 * Sanitizes title, replacing whitespace with dashes.
 *
 * Limits the output to alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-).
 * Whitespace becomes a dash.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @param string $title The title to be sanitized.
 * @return string The sanitized title.
 */
function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {
    $title = strip_tags($title);
    // Preserve escaped octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
    // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
    $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
    // Restore octets.
    $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);

    $title = remove_accents($title);
    if (seems_utf8($title)) {
        if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
        }
        $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
    }

    $title = strtolower($title);
    $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
    $title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
    $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
    $title = trim($title, '-');

    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this function as a rough placeholder. It has more flaws than you might imagine … :)
There are many plugins to improve the conversion for different languages and needs. You may take a look at my plugin [Germanix](https://github.com/toscho/Germanix-WordPress-Plugin/blob/master/germanix_url.php) to see how this could be done.

Comment: Thanks! I just had a look at your plugin, indeed there are a lot of language-specific tweaks, though French's probably slightly easier in this respect ;)

What seems strange to me, though, is that I've never seen a Wordpress-generated URL in the wild with °, `, etc. characters in them.

Do most Wordpress use a more restrictive plugin, then? Or do people just rewrite all their URLs by hand?

Mostly, I just want to remove all characters that are not `a-z0-9-` (like StackOverflow seems to be doing in their URLs too, incidentally). I'll guess I'll just end up rewriting my own funct., but it sucks

Comment: Plus, the function's documentation is just plain wrong: `Limits the output to alphanumeric characters, underscore (_) and dash (-). Whitespace becomes a dash.`. I don't get it.

Comment: @julien_c In my plugin I run `preg_replace('~([^a-z\d_.-])~', '', $str)` after the conversion to eliminate such characters. In a short test `°` seems to work in a URL. But yes, it is ugly.